# Angular JS, filter table with a select box

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I have a table. I want to filter the table depending on which value is choosen in an select box. The comparison value is {{pipe.pipe_id}} in the select box and {{dimension.pipe_id}} in the table. Guess there's a simple solution for this? Any suggestion?

```
Pipe:
    <select  id="select01">
        <option ng-repeat="pipe in pipes">{{pipe.code}} - {{pipe.title_en}}</option>
    </select>  


    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Pipe</th>
                <th>Size</th>
                <th>Inner diameter</th>
                <th>Outer diameter</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="dimension in dimensions" >
                <td>{{dimension.pipe_id}}</td>
                <td>{{dimension.nominalsize}}</td>
                <td>{{dimension.innerdiameter}}</td>
                <td>{{dimension.outerdiameter}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: With a select box, it is best to use ng-options. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would recommend using the [ng-filter](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:filter).

This link is a simple example using a to-do list.
[jsfiddle using ng-filter](http://jsfiddle.net/CagT7/)

You will need to bind whatever input you are using with `ng-model="varname"`

The ng-filter defaults to all fields in the array.  It can be filtered to a single column or point to a function in your controller.

**Search Field**

```
<select ng-model="searchparam">
   <option value="1">One</option>
   <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>
```

**To Search a single column**

```
<select ng-model="searchparam.columnOne">
   <option value="1">One</option>
   <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>
```

**Repeated Section**
*(the filter model stays the same even when your input specifies a specific column)*

```
<tr ng-repeat="dimension in dimensions | filter: searchparam">
     <td>{{dimension.columnOne}}</td>
     <td>{{dimension.columnTwo}}</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for [ng-filter](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24filter) and the `filter` filter : http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:filter