# Add filter option to the table data using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I have created a html table with static data and now I want to add filter option to the table data using angularjs.

I tried this:

```
<input type="search" placeholder="Filter" ng-model="searchtext"/> <br/><br/>

<table class="table table-hover">
   <thead>
     <th>Name</th>
     <th>Version</th>
     <th>Type</th>
   </thead>
   <tbody id="Table" class="tbody">
     <tr ng-repeat="filter:searchtext | orderBy: 'name'">
       <td>link</td>
       <td>4</td>
       <td>L1 Type</td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: you are missing the array info for your `ng-repeat`. Should start with something like `item in items | filter....`

Comment: have you tried answer from @malkus on following thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16736901/angular-js-filter-table-with-a-select-box ?

Comment: I dont want to use the values from  angular controller instead i take values from table

Comment: take a look at the docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy it tells you exactly how to orderBy, as @charlietfi says you are missing the array@  <tr ng-repeat="friend in friends | orderBy:'-age'">

Comment: you can't use `ng-repeat` on raw html table....concept is flawed. Please explain table source and expectations in more detail. Worst case you could parse the html to data array but that seems very backwards